# Is keras deep copying data when fitting the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, keras, deep-learning

When I run my model (Unet for image segmentation), I have ram memory errors poping:

```
2020-11-19 11:25:18.027748: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 11998593024 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2020-11-19 11:25:32.991088: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 11998593024 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2020-11-19 11:25:46.109554: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 11998593024 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

Allocated memory graph:

[image]

I wanted to know if tensorflow is deep copying the data, and, if it's the case, is there a way of avoiding it (without using a DataGenerator).

Main script:

```
from data_preprocessing import data_utils,DataGenerator
from model import model_utils,loss_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    X,Y = data_utils.load_all()
    print("Checkpoint 1")
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
    with strategy.scope():
        Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 1/5, shuffle = True)
        print("Checkpoint 2")
        unet = model_utils.unet(input_size=(256,256,1))
        print("Checkpoint 3")
        checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('image_segm.hdf5',monitor='loss',verbose=1,save_best_only=True)
        historic = unet.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain,epochs=1,callbacks=[checkpointer],batch_size= 5)
        print("End")
```

Edit: Using tensorflow-gpu 2.20.0 on a conda environement

Comment: The only copy of the data that could be made is to the GPU, but this happens in batches. In any case these messages are not errors, just warnings.